# How do gain permissions to access a usb formatted as ext4 in guest session?

Tags: usb-drive, format, ext4, guest-session

I formatted a usb as ext4 with gparted but when i try to access it in guest session in ubuntu 16.04, it says "you don't have the permissions necessary to access the contents of this drive"